# How to troubleshoot "Object doesn't support this property or method" error for Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1) in vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to utilise the vba code that I got from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4212-excel-insert-image-from-url.html?comment_id=14382). When I run the macro, selenium webdriver will retrieve the link of the picture and put it near to Z#. However, sometimes after generating the QR image from the website, the generated QR image will have problem to move to the Y# cell and resize.

The debug will prompt at  `Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)`, showing "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

As I will need to generate QR code for several rows of data, I am currently doing row by row.

As I said, the problem sometimes happens, but in a high frequency (90% of the time). Anyone mind to troubleshoot together? Thanks

```
  For i = 6 To Sheet2.Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Application.StatusBar = i - 1 & "/" & Sheet2.Range("D" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[contains(@type,'search')]").SendKeys (Sheet2.Range("D" & i))
            bot.Wait 1500
            Report = bot.FindElementByLinkText("EN").Attribute("href")
            bot.Get Report
            bot.Wait 1500
            QRurl = bot.FindElementByXPath("//img[contains(@src,'QRimages')]").Attribute("src")
            Sheet2.Range("Z" & i).Value = QRurl
            Sheet2.Pictures.Insert(QRurl).Select
            Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
            If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
                xcol = Sheet2.Range("Z" & i).Column - 1
                Set xRg = Cells(Sheet2.Range("Z" & i).Row, xcol)
                With Pshp
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width * 9 / 10
                    If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height * 9 / 10
                    .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
                    .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
                    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                End With
            
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("Z6").Select
    
            bot.Get "https://_/_/bulk_upload2_record.php"
            bot.Wait 1000
        Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to run the macro on the sheet I specified, otherwise all generate image will be stuck at Z"i". I assigned my button at the "navigation" sheet, that is why it didn't work out well. I tried on other sheet and run the macro as well, same outcome. So my solution is just adding a line to activate sheet2 before the for loop.